# Java - used memory is greater for fewer objects

Tags: java, performance, memory, jvm, runtime

If I create 100,000 objects the used memory is greater than the used memory for 10,000,000 objects.

Why?

**A.java**

```
public class A {

    private static final int size = 1000*100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = getMemoryInKilo();
        double start = getTime();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) { 
            new B();
        }
        double stop = getTime();
        double b = getMemoryInKilo();
        System.out.println(b-a + " KB ---> " + (stop-start)/1000+" seconds");
    }

    private static double getTime(){
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private static double getMemoryInKilo() {
        return (double)(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()- Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1000;
    }

}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B {

    private final double k = 0;
    private final int a = 1;
    private final String s = "123456789";
    private final Object o = new Object();
    private final Integer i = 10;

}
```

**Results**:

- size = 1000*100:

  **4135**.576 **KB** ---> 0.016 seconds
- size = 1000*100*100:

  **2456**.064 **KB** ---> 0.686 seconds

I run the program with those values many times and I changed the order, but the result is the same. Used memory for 100,000 objects is bigger than used memory for 10,000,000 objects.

**Details**:

- **Java 1.7**
- O.S.: **Windows 7**
- IDE: **Eclipse Kepler**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all you do is

```
new B();
```

to allocate memory, the runtime is free to recover the allocated space whenever it wants. What you're seeing is just a coincidental difference between garbage collection activity patterns.

Each "B" object you create is *immediately* a candidate for garbage collection.

Comment: I really wish I knew what it is in this answer that's worthy of a downvote.